# Deployment server feautures

Tags: assets, php

Help me to deploy expressionengine in Linux CentOS Server… Medium traffic website, we have 255 MB of database, 55 GB of static file. Provide me with proper webserver, database server, hardware configuration. Site is required to load very quickly…

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you contact the hosting provider recommended by EllisLab: https://ellislab.com/community/hosting

Also read this whitepaper supplied by them: https://www.nexcess.net/expressionengine/hosting-optimization

You could Google "expressionengine hosting" and contact numerous of the hosting providers to see what they would recommend and supply, then either choose the best/cheapest or create your own based on their recommended specs, but bear in mind, it's more than just hardware!

If you're looking for someone to do this for you, I'd suggest you create a project on the EE Job board: http://director-ee.com